# Not Able to import 'RetrieveUpdateDestoryAPIView' from 'rest_framework.generics'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am able to import other APIViews but not RetrieveUpdateDestoryAPIView using rest_framework.generics.

```
from .models import Employee
from .serializers import EmployeSerializer
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestoryAPIView

# Create your views here.
class emp_get(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeSerializer

class emp_api(RetrieveUpdateDestoryAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeSerializer
```

**File "../genericsAPIViewAndMixin/concreteApi/views.py", line 3, in 
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, DestroyAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestoryAPIView

ImportError: cannot import name 'RetrieveUpdateDestoryAPIView' from 'rest_framework.generics**

Comment: Correct to `RetrieveUpdateDestroy`, yours is `...Destory`